Jest reporting lines are uncovered when they actually are covered
I have a file reporting as only 48% covered, but when I looked at the report its very confusing because it seems like those lines are covered by tests. Example:
Settings.js
class Settings {

  general = {
      code: 'general',
      language: 'en-us',
      volume: 50,
      brightness: 75,
      notifications: true,
      autoUpdate: true,
  };
  ...

settings.test.js:
test('should initialize with default values', () => {
  const settings = new Settings();

  expect(settings.general).toEqual({
    code: 'general',
    language: 'en-us',
    volume: 50,
    brightness: 75,
    notifications: true,
    autoUpdate: true,
  });
});

The test passes and all appears to be well, except here is the resulting coverage report:

Any idea what could cause this? If it matters, we are using the v8 coverageProvider in the jest setup.

Changing the coverageProvider to babel fixed it... but that just raises more questions than it answers. Any idea what's going on here?
